# How to Start Unit Testing in React Native using jest for constant

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I m new to Unit Test and currently writing Unit Test for my TypeScript app using Jest. I m using a custom package named `common-packages` where i store all of my constant, something simple like this

```
const CLIENT_ID = 1231123123;
const TEXT = {
  Discover:"Discover",
  loading: 'loading',
  Type: "Testing",
}
const Constants = {
  TEXT,
  CLIENT_ID,
} as const;

export default Constants;
```

on my package, index.tsx. i export the `Constant`

```
export { default as Constants } from "./constants";
```

And the function that i want to test is this

```
import {Constants} from 'common-packages';

export const lockNextCardIfUncompleted = (data: any[]) => {
  if (data.length !== 0) {
    const locked = data.filter((e: any) => e.Type === Constants.TEXT.Type );
    if (locked.length === 0) return false;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

i have tried writing a unit test for lodash like this and it is working

```
const lodash = require('lodash')
test("repeat", () => {
expect(lodash.repeat("A",3)).toBe("AAA");
})
```

But for the unit test that have common-packages, it failed

```
import {
  lockNextCardIfUncompleted,
} from './fileName';

test('should return locked', () => {
  expect(
    lockNextCardIfUncompleted([
      {
        Type: 'A',
      },
    ]),
  ).toBe(false);
  expect(
    lockNextCardIfUncompleted([
      {
        Type: 'Testing,
      },
    ]),
  ).toBe(true);
});
```

It return `TypeError: Cannot read property 'TEXT' of undefined`. So the test didnt recognize the Constant from `common-package`. can anybody please help me solve this issue?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Default Exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#using_the_default_export), NOT [Named Exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#using_named_exports).

So you need to import the constants like this:

```
import Constants from 'common-packages';
```

Comment: i edited my question kind sir, added how i export it in my package index.tsx